# How to add to context.envlope in a soap request from a wsdl file ?(Python, suds)

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, suds

I want to add targetnamespace to a element in the xml schema.

I am using suds as a soap client.

For eg. the element is `<ns0:RateRequest>` and i want it to be `<ns0:RateRequest xmlns:ns0="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v18">`

I tired using regular expressions but i am not getting the result.

```
class Filter(MessagePlugin):
    def received(self, context):
        context.envelope= re.sub(r'<ns0:RateRequest>',
            '<ns0:RateRequest xmlns:ns0="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v18">', 
            context.envelope)
```

and also this

```
class Filter(MessagePlugin):
    def received(self, context):
        reply= context.reply
        context.reply= reply[reply.find("<ns0:RateRequest"):reply.rfind(' xmlns:ns0="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v18">')+1]
```

I tried the above def with `received` `sending` `marshalled`

and i call it using like this

```
client= Client(url, plugins=[Filter()])
```

i am doing this for FedEx integration and i am getting a error which i have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830651/errorcvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-ns0raterequest), by doing so i think i might solve the issue.